# Diverging implicit expansion for Ordered with Product

Tags: scala, implicit

Why is the following causing a "diverging implicit expansion":

```
trait Suit extends Ordered[Suit]

implicitly[Ordering[Suit]]     // ok
implicitly[Ordering[Product]]  // none found

implicitly[Ordering[Suit with Product]] // diverges !?
```

(Is this related to [SI-8541](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8541)?)

Comment: Forget it, Jake, it's Chinatown.